# Display a div based on user input

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I think this is simple for a more experienced programmer than myself. In Rails, using coffescript, I'd like to display additional content based on a user's selection. In practical terms, if they click on a checkbox it brings up an additional field for them to fill out, otherwise it remains hidden.

Right now the page renders without errors, but the div is not initially hidden (I thought the css would take care of this) and clicking on the checkbox does not change the state.

Here's my View (_form.html.erb):

```
 <div id="po_state">
    <%= f.label :is_holiday %><br>
      <%= f.check_box :is_holiday %>
    <div id="addStuff">
          <div class="field">        
          <%= f.label :add_stuff %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :add_stuff %> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's my css (holidays.css.scss):

```
#addStuff {
display: none;
}
```

Here's my coffeeScript (holidays.js.coffee):

```
showM = ->
  as.style.display = "block"
  return

m = document.getElementById("po_state")

as = document.getElementById("addStuff")

m.onclick = showM
```

Thought I'd try a different approach with my coffeeScript. Still no joy.

```
$("#po_state").change ->
  $("#addStuff").toggle @checked
  return
```

Comment: it's display: none;  and display: block; when you want to show it :)

Comment: DOH! Well that fixed the css, but the jQuery/CoffeeScript is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This worked. I kept it in jQuery for now. :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#po_state").click (function() {
  $("#addStuff").toggle( "bounce", 1000 );
    return false;
});
});
```